# URLLib2 urlopen is not working if we run Python script as win32 service(Windows Service)

Tags: python-2.7, urllib2, pywin32

I have URL : "http://google.com", If I run the Python script  from command prompt, then we are getting the expected result. But If we run the same code as win32 service then we are getting the following error

***urlopen error [Errno 10060] A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond***

Code Snippet:

```
class MyService(win32serviceutil.ServiceFramework):
    """NT Service."""

    _svc_name_ = "InstaMessageSyncService"
    _svc_display_name_ = "InstaMessageSyncService"

    def __init__(self, args):
        win32serviceutil.ServiceFramework.__init__(self, args)
        # create an event that SvcDoRun can wait on and SvcStop
        # can set.
        self.stop_event = win32event.CreateEvent(None, 0, 0, None)

    def SvcDoRun(self):
        global runProcess
        try:
            import urllib2
            link = "http://www.google.com"
            log.info("Going to hit URL: %s",link)
            f = urllib2.urlopen(link)
            myfile = f.read()
        except Exception,e:
            log.info("Exception: %s",e)
        win32event.WaitForSingleObject(self.stop_event, win32event.INFINITE)

    def SvcStop(self):
        runProcess = False
        self.ReportServiceStatus(win32service.SERVICE_STOP_PENDING)
        win32event.SetEvent(self.stop_event)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    win32serviceutil.HandleCommandLine(MyService)
```

Comment: Don't you have proxy settings unavailable at System level (only set for your user and not for _LocalSystem_)?

Answer (score 0):

looks like you have your firewall taking action.
Try to turn off the firewall, if it helps then you should turn it off for this service by allowing the ports or the service (by its name).

See microsoft help page for details:
https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc757622(v=ws.10).aspx

Comment: firewall is turned off for all the services, even though it is not working.